# MobaxTerm set default home directory for SSh session

Tags: putty, session, home-directory, mobaxterm

In MobaxTerm, Putty saved sessions, I would like for it to open another directory rather than `/home/myuser` under SCP navigation. I am working in another dir and every time after opening the session I need to navigate into `/home/myuser/my/current/working/dir/now/` to get my files.
Another option is perhaps creating a shortcut on `/home/myuser` that points to the needed dir ?

How can we achieve either of this ? I can't seem to find an answer on Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your sessions in mobaxterm, you can easily add a change path in Advanced Settings / Execute command "cd /home/myuser/my/current/working/dir/now/" which will put you immediately to the suggested folder. Furthermore be sure that follow path feature is activated. If your target system is an AIX based server you need to add an pwd - not necessary in linux:

Execute would like that "cd /home/myuser/my/current/working/dir/now/;pwd" (pwd seems to refresh the output and the sftp browser gets approbiate information than)